# QML Access object property by property name string

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to create a QML binding in a repeated component. I want to bind the value of one of the elements to a property from a known object. My problem is that the name of said property that I want to bind to will be provided as a string in the component. How can I resolve the property name to an actual property that can be used as the value in a binding?

PS. If possible I guess I could pass the property directly to the repeater but then I would like to be able to convert the property to a string because I need both and don't want to pass both.

EDIT:
Here's what I want:

```
    ListModel {
        id: settingsModel
        ListElement { title: "Bed Width"; setting: "bedWidth"; }
        ListElement { title: "Bed Length"; setting: "bedLength"; }
    }

    Component {
        id: settingsDelegate

        Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: childrenRect.height

            Label {
                id: setLabel
                text: title + ":"
                width: parent.width
            }

            TextBox {
                id: setTBox
                anchors.top: setLabel.bottom
                anchors.topMargin: 5
                width: parent.width

                Binding on text {
                    when: !setTBox.isActive
                    value: settings.setting
                }

                Binding {
                    target: settings
                    property: setting
                    value: setTBox.text
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        id: settingsColumn
        spacing: 10
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: txtSave.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 15

        Repeater {
            model: settingsModel
            delegate: settingsDelegate
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @ddriver I haven't actually tried anything because I can't think of anything that might even work

Comment: It doesn't have to work, it just as to illustrate intent and effort.

Comment: @ddriver ok, I've added the type of thing that I want

Comment: What is `tBox` and `settings`?

Comment: @ddriver Ok sorry tbox was a typo but setting is a registered class/object that contains bindable values, I've now fixed all the typos...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My problem is that the name of said property that I want to bind to
>   will be provided as a string in the component. How can I resolve the
>   property name to an actual property that can be used as the value in a
>   binding?

If you look at [the documentation for `Binding`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html#property-prop) you will discover that the `property` property expects a string - `property : string`

So you don't have anything to resolve, that happens internally.

> my problem is the "value: settings.setting" line

You could try something like `settings[setting]`

Comment: Yes at the one end that works but my problem is the "value: settings.setting" line on the other binding

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Gerharddc - if you plan on using QML extensively, you might want to learn the basics of JavaScript. It will save you lots of time. Your problem was just standard JS stuff.

Comment: So was I, but the last couple of years I dare say I replaced about 90% of the C++ with JS, much easier and faster to prototype. I just focus on a flexible and extensible C++ core and do most of the stuff in QML. It really helps when you don't need to recompile for every single tiny change, and you don't get hard crashes on bugs :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind should I one day become a permanent Qt user