# How to access a qml property from its name as a string?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

My question is very similar to [QML Access object property by property name string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387130/qml-access-object-property-by-property-name-string) except I would like to access a root property...

I would like to be able to do that:

```
Rectangle {
    property string color1: "blue"
    property string color2: "red"
    property string curColor : "color1"

    color: /*something like*/ currentScope[curColor]
}
```

Note : this is a MWE, I know there are much smarter way of doing it in this case. My use case is to provide a simple to use Adapter that needs to know on which property it must act. I know about Binding, but it requires and id... I would like to avoid using an explicit id and work in the current scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give your `Rectangle` an id so you can reference it.

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property string color1: "blue"
    property string color2: "red"
    property string curColor : "color1"

    color: root[curColor]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
To do it without an id, you can use the `this` pointer. It is in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html#javascript-environment-restrictions), but not easy to find.

```
Rectangle {
    property string color1: "blue"
    property string color2: "red"
    property string curColor : "color1"

    color: this[curColor]
}
```

Comment: And I precisly specified that I didn't want to add an id to speed up writing the code... and because the component would be actually used as an child adapter  >.<

Comment: Guess I should have read all the way to the end. But I don't get why avoiding ids would speed anything up.